# how to fix this error: No module named 'allauth'?

Tags: django, facebook-login, django-allauth, django-settings

I want to use allauth in django API but when I installed it I got some errors I fixed it by django.setup() and after that, I get the error which tells me that I have to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE now I did that in manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
import django


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'website.settings'
    django.setup()
    main()
```

but I get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
```

please can anyone tells me how can I fix that exception error? I did many searches but I get no help and I asked here but also I got no help so, please if anyone can help me!

**Additional information:**
that is what I did in settings.py after I installed allauth by pip3

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'index.apps.IndexConfig',
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'community.apps.CommunityConfig',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

and in urls.py

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

**Edit post:**

by using virtualenv that Trace has raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/auth_backends.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/media/abdelhamedabdin/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/ripo/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
```

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv`? Is it activated?

Comment: Yes, I'm using virtualenv and it is activated

Comment: Try running `python -m pip install allauth` when your virtualenv is active

Comment: I was run the code by Pycharm's command that I activate virtualenv into it and the above exception I typed it was raised because I was using Linux's terminal without run virtualenv so, now I have a new exception by Pycharm's command. I did edit the post you can see it now @Charnel

Comment: that doesn't work with me. could you show the edited post and show the new trace @IainShelvington

Answer (score 16):

By installing `django-allauth` as follows:

```
python -m pip install django-allauth
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem and the main problem was spin around `allauth.account` that I want to migrate it into `INSTALLED_APPS` also, I had an additional app in this case, `'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'`, those apps was the reason for the problems.
for the first app (allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend)I was getting an error that tells me that I am not able to migrate the INSTALLED_APPS without migrating allauth app first.
for the second app (allauth.account) I was getting an error **duplicate 'account'** because I have already application with that name so, I had to rename the app name which already exists to name like accounts for example until I can install allauth.account succeeded.
until I am able to specify one error of each app I was migrating each one separately to show the specific error to it but when I was migrating the both together I was getting that Traceback I specified above.

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend', from INSTALLED_APPS. As it is to be part of

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

Answer (score -1):

as I check and try you should create virtualenv without that does't work , but still confused why